# Keeping Properties When Converting JSON to SHP

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, json

I'm  trying to convert the [Nielsen map of DMAs](http://bl.ocks.org/simzou/6459889) from a JSON to a shapefile. The properties of the json is as formatted like this:

```
  "id": 546,
          "properties": {
            "name": "dma:",
            "latitude": 33.896366,
            "tvperc": 88.6,
            "dma": 546,
            "dma1": "Columbia, SC",
            "cableperc": 50.5,
            "adsperc": 38.8,
            "longitude": -80.9102195
```

However, when I drag the json to QGIS, the ID and the name column are the only thing that are retained. Similarly, when I try to convert this to a shapefile through `ogr2ogr`, the same thing occurs. Is there a way I can keep the properties? I know I can use the `-select` parameter but there are no examples on how to use this anywhere in the documentation. My code is below.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" nielsentopo.json "usa-dma.shp"
```

Comment: You need a [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) format

Comment: Ahh gotcha, is there anyway I can do that? Much of the discussion is converting geoJSON to topoJSON and not the other way around. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert the [Nielsen data](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/simzou/6459889/raw/462e932bd8f1db643f16aca3126e3c7434582e1a/nielsentopo.json) from topojson to geojson. One way to do this is with [this online topojson to geojson tool](http://jeffpaine.github.io/geojson-topojson/).

From there, copy and save the resulting geojson to a new file, then you can convert to shapefile, etc.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.geo.json
```